# Cannot push into ruby array

Tags: ruby, arrays, push

I am writing a new accessor and it has its own array variable to keep information but when I try to call class_eval in its method, the push method on that variable doesn't work.

Its a method written in Class and the class_eval line reads as follows:

```
class_eval "def #{attr_name}=(value); #{attr_name} = value; #{information}.push value; end; def #{attr_name}_history; #{information}; end"
```

so the push in this line doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that whatever string is stored by the local variable `information` when you call the `class_eval` is actually a method on the class that you're adding this function to.

The following works, because I make sure the class has a `history` method.

```
class A
  def history
    @history ||= []
  end
end

attr_name = "foo"
information = "history"
A.class_eval "def #{attr_name}=(value); #{attr_name} = value; #{information}.push value; end; def #{attr_name}_history; #{information}; end"

a = A.new
a.foo = "bar"
a.foo = "baz"
a.foo_history
```

Comment: what if there is also a.bar and a.another and so on. would this keep separate copies of those variables

Comment: In this example, `attr_name` evaluates to "foo" _before_ the `class_eval` is executed, so it only adds a history for one param. You could write a mixin that runs this logic for every variable you mention, or that even looks at instance_variables and automatically adds it.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work because "#{information}" will return the *string* value of `information`, not the actual Array object itself. This is because it is substituted for a string when it is built.

You have to change it to a variable that is part of both the scope of the object you're working in, and the class you're doing things to. For example, try changing it to something like:

```
Foo::Information = [...]
class_eval "
  class_eval "
  def #{attr_name}=(value)
    #{attr_name} = value
    Foo::Information.push value
  end
  def #{attr_name}_history
    Foo::Information
  end"
  "
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `information` variable should be initialized as an array, then you can call `push` method on it. Something like this:

```
def #{attr_name}=(value); 
  #{attr_name} = value; 
  (#{information}||=[]).push value; 
end; 
def #{attr_name}_history; 
  #{information}; 
end
```

BTW, your formating is ugly, so you have to think twice next time.

Comment: i was trying to do it multiline but i couldn't get the %Q to work on the IDE, if you mean that